# Request to Graph API returns 400 Bad Request response; expecting Graph API error code

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

We are sending a request to facebook's Graph API to update an Ad Set's `end_time` via JavaScript using the node-fetch npm package:

```
const data = {
  end_time: fields.endTime,
  access_token: FB_ADS_TOKEN
}

const options = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
  body: JSON.stringify(data)
}

const url = `${FB_GRAPH_ENDPOINT}/${fields.adSetId}`

return fetch(url, options)
  .then(response => {
    if (response.status != 200) {
      throw `status: ${response.status} - ${response.statusText}`
    }
```

When sending a data value that I expect to give me a code 100, subcode 1885272 (Invalid parameter, Budget too low), `response.status` is 400 and `response.statusText` is Bad Request.

The same request url used in the Graph API Explorer yields the expected error code. The url is good, as it successfully updates with an `end_time` that meets the criteria for budget.

How can I get the correct Graph API error code?

Comment: I don't think GAE sends `application/json`, and looking at the cURL code example at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-campaign#Updating, it only sends name=value pairs using `-F`, so that means your normal `Content-Type: multipart/form-data`

Comment: Thanks for the comment. This doesn't seem to make a difference and when using json, the request gets sent successfully. I am receiving the same response when sending with form-data.
I guess I am really expecting a 2xx response with the Graph API error code as a return code.